# Nested queries Date range

Tags: mongodb

I have a project where I embeds date ranges in a document.

Something like the following:

```
{ "availabilities" : [  
  { "start_date" : ISODate("2012-06-28T00:00:00Z"), "end_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T00:00:00Z") },     
  { "start_date" : ISODate("2012-10-08T00:00:00Z"), "end_date" : ISODate("2012-10-28T00:00:00Z") }]
}
```

What I need to do is find all the documents that are available during a certain period
I use a query like this one:

```
db.faces.find({"availabilities" : {"$elemMatch" : {"$and" : [{"start_date" : {"$lte" : ISODate('2012-10-01 00:00:00 UTC')}}, {"end_date" : {"$gte": ISODate('2012-10-07 00:00:00 UTC')}}]}}})
```

But it won't use my indexes:

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
    "availabilities.start_date" : 1,
    "availabilities.end_date" : 1
  },
  "ns" : "faces_development.faces",
  "name" : "availabilities.start_date_1_availabilities.end_date_1"
}
```

When I do an explain on the query, the output for the indexBounds is quite strange and I don't understand it.

```
{
  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor availabilities.start_date_1_availabilities.end_date_1",
  "isMultiKey" : true,
  "n" : 71725,
  "nscannedObjects" : 143019,
  "nscanned" : 143019,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 143221,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 143221,
  "scanAndOrder" : false,
  "indexOnly" : false,
  "nYields" : 2,
  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
  "millis" : 1608,
  "indexBounds" : {
    "availabilities.start_date" : [
        [
          true,
          ISODate("2012-10-01T00:00:00Z")
        ]
      ],
    "availabilities.end_date" : [
      [
        {
          "$minElement" : 1
        },
        {
          "$maxElement" : 1
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "server" : "foobar.local:27017"
}
```

Current version of mongoDB: MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0

How must I do to use indexes?

Trying to find related questions and bugs on mongodb without great success.

Comment: I don't know what this indexBounds means but the "cursor: 'BtreeCursor'" means that it's using the index.

Comment: Hmm one of your index bounds has "true" as the value? You might find your data is not clean. It is true that is using the index however for some reason the index is causing a much wider scan than it should as it is scanning 143019 but it is only returning 71725. It could be the use of $gt and $lt inside the elemmatch and unclean data

Answer (score 1):

This will scan less of the index in 2.3: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3104

Meanwhile, I suggest moving each availability into its own document, instead of having many in one array, for more efficient querying.